# python - convert date and time to datetime in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I would like to merge column date and column time in a DataFrame to create a datetime object.
The DataFrame is imported from clipboard, then I assume that everything is in string format.

I used the following code and got the following error:

```
    new_data
    Out[90]: 
           date      time  price  price2  price3  price4  var  volume
    0  29/09/21  05:07:07      1       1       1       1    1       1
    1  01/10/21  06:03:07      1       1       1       1    1       1
    
    new_data.time=(new_data.date+';'+new_data.time)
    
    new_data
    Out[92]: 
           date               time  price  price2  price3  price4  var  volume
    0  29/09/21  29/09/21;05:07:07      1       1       1       1    1       1
    1  01/10/21  01/10/21;06:03:07      1       1       1       1    1       1
    
    pandas.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%d/%m/%Y;%H:%M:%S')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "C:\Users\PC1\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 456, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
        values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    
      File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 350, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
    
    TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
    
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "<ipython-input-93-74451701a415>", line 1, in <module>
        pandas.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%d/%m/%Y;%H:%M:%S')
    
      File "C:\Users\PC1\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 805, in to_datetime
        values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    
      File "C:\Users\PC1\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 460, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
        raise e
    
      File "C:\Users\PC1\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 424, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
        arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    
      File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
    
    ValueError: time data '29/09/21;05:07:07' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y;%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

can you please show me how to solve?
thanks

EDIT: thanks to Filippo comment. The **Solution** is to use y instead of Y because in this case the year format has 2 digits:

```
    pandas.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%d/%m/%Y;%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: `%Y` is full length year, if you want last two digits you should use `%y`

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Filippo comment. The Solution is to use y instead of Y because in this case the year format has 2 digits:

```
pandas.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%d/%m/%Y;%H:%M:%S')
```